# Unable to upload profile picture in an app while recording in jmeter but when i am not recording i am able to upload it

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing

I want to record the script for signup page and to complete it I have to upload a profile picture but when I try to upload it i am able to view the pictures that I have in my mobile through the app but when I select it and upload ,it doesn't get uploaded and when I submit it asks to upload profile picture 1st.
I don't know how to proceed is there any permission that needs to be given to access files from my mobile to that app?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to record a file upload using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) there is one simple rule to follow:

**The file(s) you're going to upload need to be present in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation**

only this way JMeter will be able to properly generate [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager).

More information: [JMeter Performance Testing: Upload and Download Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-testing)

Comment: i copied he jpeg file to bin folder of apache jmeter. but still i could not upload the profile pic